# Find an equation for the tangent to the curve at the given point.

Tags: calculus

$$y = x^2-x, \;(3,6) $$

I know that eventually I will have to use slope equation to get the answer which is $y = 5x-9$ but I do not understand how to get to that answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We know lines have the form $y=mx+b$. First, we want $m$, the slope. We get that by taking the derivative of $y$. So we have 
$$
y'(x)=2x-1
$$
via the power rule. Then we have $y'(3)=5$. So we know we want a line of slope $5$. So $m=5$. We also know that the lines needs to go through the point $(3,6)$. So we have
$$
6=5(3)+b
$$
which gives $b=-9$. Therefore, the tangent line to $y=x^2-x$ at $(3,6)$ is the line $y=5x-9$.

Comment: I think you mean $5x-9$ in your last line.

Comment: @Daryl Yes, thank you. Corrected.